# How to reuse index already present on file system in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, search, lucene, hibernate-search

```
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
```

from: http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/

Everytime I start my application I get progress and on file system the index resets and regrows. Is there any way to reuse index from file system?

```
...
    .b.i.SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor  : HSEARCH000031: Indexing speed: 349.166779 documents/second; progress: 89.76%
    2016-12-07 10:57:21.511   INFO 27174 --- [ entityloader-1] o.h.s.b.i.SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor  : HSEARCH000030: 35900 documents indexed in 102821 ms
    ...
```

Current settings

```
properties.hibernate.search.default.directory_provider: filesystem
properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase: /tmp/index
```

maybe I need another directory provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the *MassIndexer* every time you start your application.
Just delete those two lines of code.

The *filesystem* directory provider stores the index permanently on the directory you have chosen. Beware that stuff in `/tmp` might be cleaned up by other processes on your system.